# SqlDataAdapter.Update() won't update multiple columns of database (C#)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldataadapter

I have a form where the user can edit several parameters, and after pressing the save button these changes should be pushed to the database. However, only the first change made is actually updated. This is, given the code below only the "notes" field is saved.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow row = dsCustomers.Tables["tblCustomers"].Rows[comboBoxCustomers.SelectedIndex];
        row["notes"] = tCompanyNotes.Text;
        row["visit_address"] = tVisiting.Text;
        objConnectCustomers.UpdateDatabase(dsCustomers);
    }
```

and the UpdateDatabase method:

```
public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
```

where da_1 is an SqlDataAdapter created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with C# but I think you are not looping through all the row to update. Hope this article I have come across would help you. Here is the link [Add a Record to the Dataset and Update the Database](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p9.html)

Comment: That's actually the tutorial I was using, in particular this part:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p10.html
Adding a new row works just fine.